# How many tags are allowed in tdengine

Tags: tdengine

I'm using the tdengine, I was curious about the max mumber of tags that it allow.from the documentations that I read from their official  website i didn’t.t find any limitation about the maximum Of tag counts. So I was confused about this does tdengine limit the tag account? If limit how many tags are allowed or it can be configured?
Does any one knows this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the maximum tags allowed in TDengine database is 128, and the total length of all the tags should be less than 16k characters.
this info can be found from here: [TAOS SQL Boundary Restrictions](https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/taos-sql)

- Max number of tags allowed is 128, down to 1, and total length of tags does not exceed 16k characters